# Android Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to get bluetooth low energy advertisement out from my android phone. I realize that android only supports the central or observer mode for now. Is there any other Bluetooth stack that I could use in order to advertise packets? What are the options that I have currently?

Comment: Short of rooting the phone, waiting for platform changes, or plugging in an external BLE adapter (for example with USB host mode if supported)?  None.

Comment: Is there any way to get access to the hcitools command. If I do then I can access the leadv command which starts advertising. Would this be possible to do if I root the phone?

Comment: As per my knowledge if the Bluetooth Stack is BlueZ then hcitool can be accessed if phone is rooted. BlueZ implement the hcitool .

Answer (score 0):

Android introduced peripheral role support from Android 5.0. You can try that out.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Wireless

And for your information android stopped using Bluez stack from Android 4.3 onwards it now uses Bluedroid stack

Comment: having a link of tutorial is less appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Android has officially introduced it in Android 5.0. If you want to use it in previous version, you can use AltBeacon Library. It make BLE things much simpler than Android library. 
https://altbeacon.org/